# How to update Webstorm in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ide, webstorm

I have Webstorm in Linux, and I am getting an alert indicating there is an update, I am trying to get some info from the web, but everything I get is HOW TO INSTALL IT and nothing regarding how to update it.

So, what should I do to update my Webstorm ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on update type. If a patch update is available, you are normally prompted to update and restart - on restarting the patch is applied. But patch updates are only available for subsequent minor releases. In other cases, you need to download the full installation package from main downloads page and install it into the empty directory (NOT over existing installation!) When updating to a new major version, you will be prompted to import your settings from previous installation on the first start

Answer (score 7):

This leaves the launcher broken. Pointing to the old directory. Easy to fix in KDE but a bitch in gnome.

How do you upgrade to a new version of WebStorm without breaking your launcher?

---

Update: This is for Ubuntu Gnome 16.04...

Ok. I figured it out. Here's how to fix it. In the terminal navigate to `/usr/share/applications`

`cd /usr/share/applications`

Delete the old launcher...

`sudo rm jetbrains-webstorm.desktop`

Navigate to the directory where `webstorm.sh` is installed. In my case it's `/opt/WebStorm-162.1121.31/bin`. Run it as a super user...

`sudo ./webstorm.sh`

In the splash screen, select "Configure | Create Desktop Entry" from the menu in the bottom right corner. Since you launched it as `sudo`, just accept the super user warning, and you will have a new launcher. Quit WebStorm, close the terminal, and now you can launch WebStorm from the applications menu.

Comment: Note that if you didn't install Webstorm for all users, the launcher location is `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Ignore the proposed update by clicking Ignore This Update. This way, you will add the proposed build’s number to the Ignored updates list.
2. Open the PhpStorm Settings / Preferences dialog and navigate to Appearance and Behavior | System Settings | Updates.
3. Click the Check Now button to check for available updates. If you only skipped a single update, the update dialog box will now prompt you to update and restart PhpStorm. Otherwise, keep ignoring the proposed updates until a patch-based update is proposed.
4. Update and restart PhpStorm.
5. Navigate back to the Updates settings page and click the View/edit ignored updates link to open the Ignored updates list.
6. Delete the ignored build’s number from this list and check for available updates once more. The update that you have un-ignored will show up, and you can now apply it as a patch as well. Note that if you have ignored several updates, you need to remove and apply them one by one, starting from the oldest update.